# Linq2SQL Filter on multi columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

If I have a data table like this

```
id, Name, Address, Status
```

How would I in Linq search across multiple columns?

So if I enter a search term of "slappy" I'd want all matches in columns Name, Address and Status.

Is there an easy way or do I need to apply `contains` for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var searchTerm = "slappy";
var result = context.table.Where(row => row.Name.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                        row.Address.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                        row.Status.Contains(searchTerm));
```

Comment: Heh, exactly what I was trying to avoid.  I didn't think there would be a way.

Comment: I don't think there is any mechanism to search all properties. I guess you could use reflection but it would perform very poorly.

Comment: Agreed.  The problem is that I'd like a way to search even if the model changes.  Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use a search engine library? 
It is not based on EF, but EF is not the best choice for your purpose. Surely you can mix technologies.
http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Comment: I could but the CTO won't allow it.